# WCF service application does not accept my bindings

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding

**WCF** service applications are configured to only accept limited amount & sizes of data; We need to revoke this limit. I've been trying to use bindings and I've read a lot of threads on StackOverflow, as well as other resources.

However, the web service still doesn't seem to accept my bindings and returns **Error 413 request entity to large** when I send large data. I honestly have very little experience with WCF services, so my error must be something trivial. But after hours, I can't seem to know what it is.

Also I'm not exactly sure what to define in the WCF web.config and what belongs in the desktop application app.config, so maybe I'm wrong about this as well.

Currently, the WCF service is running on localhost (Visual Studio 2013).

---

**WPF Client application app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00">
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:52911/Service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyWebService.IService" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**WCF service application Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <protocolMapping>
            <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
        </protocolMapping>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="v11.0" />
            </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Entities" connectionString="[...]" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: try enabling streaming of the request entity

Comment: I tried it (code in question updated) and now I get a 400 Bad Request. Also I'm still not sure what belongs in which config file, as the app.config of the WPF application seems to get entirely overwritten.

Comment: @bytecode77, on the client side the <netTpBinding> configuration section is useless because you ve got no netTcp endpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server, you should configure `basicHttpsBinding` and/or `basicHttpBinding`  to change the sizes.

Under `<system.serviceModel>`, you should add something like :

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <basicHttpsBinding>
    <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpsBinding>
</bindings>
```

**Note** :
 The binding configurations have no name attribute so it applies to every binding instance of the same class.

Regards